# Center a page with a fixed element

Tags: jquery

I have 3 issues with my site (hope this isn't cheating! :p) that I'm currently building (using Wordpress by the way...)

I'm trying to achieve something fairly straight-forward, but its proving to be a little tricky. On this my page ([www.ashleymosuro.com/newsite](http://www.ashleymosuro.com/newsite)) I have a fixed navigation bar on the left which doesn't scroll with the other elements.

However, what I would preferably want is for the entire page to be centred, or at least the main wrapper with all of the content. I managed to do this before, but whenever I resized the page the wrapper would move to the left allowing the navigation to overlap it. I want the navigation to remain the same distance away from the wrapper, but have it all centred regardless of whether the page is resized.

My other issue is that I currently have a horizontal scrollbar appearing on the site, as if there is more content to the right of the page. I assume this is a float issue?

I would also like my fixed navigation to *do something* once it has reached the footer div. I know that this is possible with jQuery but not entirely sure how to achieve it. I guess I need to somehow add a class to the navigation ONLY when it is colliding with the footer, but when the user scrolls back up it needs to remove this class.

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Ashley

Comment: re three issues: no, it isn't cheating, but it is less likely to get helpful answers on SO than if you posted them as separate questions.  :)

Comment: Sorry, off topic but couldn't help it, there's a funny contradiction in your headers: "I'm asley mosuro, I am designer, I focus specifically on the web ... I also do print"

Comment: Revolving gallery is too fast. Could not read who you are. Or I might be a slow reader

Comment: Its still being built guys, but thanks for the comments. You're very right about the text copy too. I need to read over the whole site once I have the functionality sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to center any div by giving it an absolute position with a left value of 50% and a left marginal pixel value of negative half the pixel dimension of the width of the div.

So If you had a div with a width of say 955 px, to center it you would give it an absolute position with a left value of 50% and a left marginal value of -477.5, and it should stay centered regardless.

As for the horizontal scroll bar, you should set the pixel dimension of the body to 100% for both width and height, that way your page will resize to the users resolution.